# Static variable cannot be found by name when debugging

Tags: c, debugging, static, iar

I have a static variable in one of my compilation units, which is compiled with no optimizations:

```
static __no_init enum_type status;
```

I'm trying to watch this variable in the debugger, but I cannot find it. Stepping through the functions which update `status` I can see expected values to be written to a particular memory address, 0xFB9F8.

However, that memory address seems to have no name. Here's what the linker map shows:

```
NEAR_N
  Relative segment, address: 000FB9F8 - 000FB9F8 (0x1 bytes), align: 0
  Segment part 3.             Intra module refs:   function1
                                                   function2
```

Indeed, `function1`, `function2` etc. are function which access that variable.

How do I make that variable visible in the debugger?

Comment: Could you please add a tag for the architecture you are using? This problem/solution may be limited to certain versions of EW. I know that option does not exist in EWARM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution when the question was already half-written, so I decided to post it with a self-answer.

Anyway, there is a setting in the linker options which does just what I need and is unsurprisingly called "Module-local symbols":

[image]

Setting it to "Include all" makes static variables available to the debugger.